# Teams Bot Framework: v3/conversations API return status 400 Bad Request

Tags: microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I am trying to start a new conversation with bot (following MS docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-send-and-receive-messages?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) by using `v3/conversations` API.

Here is my configurations:

URL: `https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apac/v3/conversations` (`https://smba.trafficmanager.net/apac/` is service URL I got from request when I send a message to the bot)

Method: POST

Data:

```
{
    "bot": {
        "id": "28:90e5948c-591d-4275-9975-9d02088e8eed",
        "name": "bot-pro",
        "role": "bot"
    },
    "isGroup": false,
    "members": [
        {
            "id": "29:1quZ9DuVG3b5ndoC0Kna1xVx65mnaLiXHnpm4xaVxsNogifR54F28CJ2CwRT9tRhn12TjOefO3XMggEABAcCJ6g",
            "name": "user abc"
        }
    ],
    "topicName": "News Alert"
}
```

I used Postman to test this API, and I received response Json with status 400:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadSyntax",
        "message": "Bad format of conversation ID"
    }
}
```

Where I wrong?

Comment: Could you please try with another member Id? Sometimes Not all channels support group conversations. Consult the channel's documentation to determine whether a channel supports group conversations and to identify the maximum number of participants that a channel allows in a conversation.

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT thanks for your comment. I resolved this problem, my request JSON missing tenantID parameter